# Как использовать аттрибут dangerouslySetInnerHTML в связке react и kotlin js

Tags: reactjs, kotlin

Собственно есть некий текст приходящий с бека вида `"<h1>Привет</h1>"` 
как его отобразить в виде полноценного "Привет" с учетом тегов? 
Может есть более удобные варианты чем dangerouslySetInnerHTML?

Answer (score 2):

В общем я нашел как в котлин/реакт заюзать dangerouslySetInnerHTML
 `div {
     attrs["dangerouslySetInnerHTML"] = InnerHTML("<h1>Привет</h1>")
 }`
таким образом там можно любой атрибут указать

Answer (score 1):

Свойству `innerHTML` в DOM браузера соответствует [`dangerouslySetInnerHTML`](https://ru.reactjs.org/docs/dom-elements.html#dangerouslysetinnerhtml) в React. Как правило, вставка HTML из кода рискованна, так как можно случайно подвергнуть ваших пользователей [атаке межсайтового скриптинга](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%9C%D0%B5%D0%B6%D1%81%D0%B0%D0%B9%D1%82%D0%BE%D0%B2%D1%8B%D0%B9_%D1%81%D0%BA%D1%80%D0%B8%D0%BF%D1%82%D0%B8%D0%BD%D0%B3). Таким образом, вы можете вставить HTML непосредственно из React используя `dangerouslySetInnerHTML` и передать объект с ключом `__html`, чтобы напомнить себе, что это небезопасно. Например:

```
function createMarkup() {
  return {__html: '<h1>Привет</h1>'};
}

function MyComponent() {
  return <div dangerouslySetInnerHTML={createMarkup()} />;
}
```

Помимо минуса в виде межсайтового скриптинга есть и небольшой плюс. Когда вы используете `dangerouslySetInnerHTML`, это указывает React на то, что HTML внутри этого компонента не контролируется React. Поскольку React использует виртуальный DOM, когда он сравнивает diff с фактическим DOM, он может обойти проверку дочерних узлов этого узла, поскольку он уже знает, что HTML-код поступает из другого источника. Так что в этом месте присутствует некоторое повышение производительности.

Собственно, [`dangerouslySetInnerHTML`](https://ru.reactjs.org/docs/dom-elements.html#dangerouslysetinnerhtml) и есть тот способ, с помощью которого можно отобразить HTML-код из другого источника. Но есть еще способ установки HTML через `innerHTML`, однако узел DOM будет обновляться с введенным HTML так же, как и у `dangerouslySetInnerHTML`.

Если вы просто используете `innerHTML`, React не сможет узнать, был ли изменен узел DOM. В следующий раз, когда вызывается функция рендеринга, React перезапишет содержимое, которое было введено вручную в `innerHTML`, с тем, что, по его мнению, должно быть правильным состоянием этого узла DOM.

Полезные ссылки для ознакомления:

- [How can I render HTML from another file in a React component?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/33980020/5275890)
- [React.js: Set innerHTML vs dangerouslySetInnerHTML](https://stackoverflow.com/a/37339542/5275890)